# K fold Cross validation for negative binomial regression using caret package?

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I was using the "caret" package to perform a K fold cross-validation on a negative binomial regression model (glm.nb) for an overdispersed count data set. I think the approach I used is incorrect due to the warnings.

Is there a method to perform cross-validation on models created using glm.nb function? Comments are highly appreciated.

**The code**

```
data_ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)
# Run the negtaive binomial regression model
model_caret <- train(Count~Soil.Sal+Temp+Soil.ph, data = CLAB,trControl=data_ctrl, method="lm")
model_caret
model_caret$finalModel
```

**The output**

```
Negative Binomial Generalized Linear Model 

102 samples
  3 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 81, 82, 82, 82, 81 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  link      RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
  identity       NaN        NaN       NaN
  log       7.680947  0.3695579  5.186753
  sqrt      6.727719  0.3854733  4.751341

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
The final value used for the model was link = sqrt

Warnings (12)
Warning messages:
1: In log(y/mu) : NaNs produced
2: model fit failed for Fold1: link=identity Error : no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
```

Comment: cv.glm function in "boot" package gave the following values, but I don't know how to interpret them. CVbest$delta, [1] 50.14789 49.53081